# Rails Activerecord - chaining associations to query existence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, models

Say I have the models Lists, People, Outfit.

Lists have many people, people have many lists and one outfit. What is the most efficient way of checking if an outfit attribute 'name' exists in a given list with active-record?

I would like this to return as a boolean if possible

Comment: what's the relationship between List and Outfit? Not sure I understand "if an outfit attribute 'name' exists in a given list ".

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have these associations on your models (`people` in `Outfit` model and `lists` in `Person` model) and I got what you are asking this one should work for me

```
Outfit.joins(people: :lists).exists?(lists: {id: your_list_id}, name: 'your_outfit_name')
```

and it's just one SQL query

In alternative, you could just have

```
Outfit.joins(:lists).exists?(lists: {id: your_list_id}, name: 'your_outfit_name')
```

and an association like

```
has_many :lists, through: :people
```

This is the idea but I find hard try this kind of stuff